# check file is selected or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding = 0 cellspacing=0>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input style="align:center;" class="multi" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="pic1" name="picture">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="pic2" class="multi" name="picture">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="pic3" class="multi" name="picture">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="pic4" class="multi" name="picture">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="pic5" class="multi" name="picture">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" style="border:0 none;width:30%; font-size:20px;height:35px;background-color:#44C1D3;color:white;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

i want to check if any one input file is selected.
may be its first or last. i just want to generate some popup if no file is seleted.but if one file is selected it returns true

Comment: I don't get it... you use `multiple` but also 5 inputs.... like one was not enough :)

Comment: One is not working fine in webview so i hev to use 5 and i have used this code                                                                                       function validatPicture(){
    $check = true;
       $(".multi").each(function(){
          var files = $(this).val(); 

           if(files=='') { 
              alert("No File Selected");
              $check = false;
              return false; // You don't want to loop, so exit each loop
           }
       });
       return $check;
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#pic1').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(this.files)
    }
)
```

This will detect a file selection on the first input type. You can fetch the files attribute of each input tag and make a decision based on that.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwobenbt/

EDIT: Here is the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/uwobenbt/5/

```
function test() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.multi').each(
        function(d){
            if(this.files.length != 0) count ++
        }
    )
    if(count) alert('files are selected')
    else alert ('no files selected')
}
```